# values assigned to node.js variable return strange values

Tags: node.js, variables

I am getting hands-on Node.js, and I found it pretty exciting. However, when I was trying to work out with variables I got strange results. When 01234 is assigned to a variable, 668 is displayed as response and when 0123 is assigned, 83 is returned as the response. I failed to understand logic. I am attaching this screengrab.

[image]

I checked same in c# and I got expected result. What is happening here in node.js?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, starting with `0` is indicating this number is in `octal`

`012 = 2 + 1 * 8 = 10`

Referenced here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix

Answer (score 2):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

So `012` is an An octal numeral so that's why it is equal to `10` in the decimal.

A good solution is to parse it.

```
parseInt("012");
```